# srand(time(NULL)) function

Tags: c, random, srand, time.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void){

    int x = rand()%100;
    printf("%d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

The code above generates a random number correctly. Is this correct? But, other sources always **include  library and srand(time(NULL))**. Why do we have to include **include  library and srand(time(NULL))**? Are there any reasons to include?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main( void){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int x = rand()%100;
    printf("%d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the first case it is always the *same* random number each time you run the program. The second case "seeds" the RNG.

Answer (score 3):

Because if you run this code many times, you will get the same result! (also, `rand()` return the same result in each run). Hence, you can initialize the seed of random in each run of the code to get a different random result by `srand`. Using `time(NULL)` to set a different seed of random through `srand`.

Answer (score 0):

`srand` is a random number generator function which will randomize the number produced by `rand` function.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have a (huge) library with (huge) books filled with (apparently random, but fixed) numbers.

When you do `rand()` you get the current number on the current book and advance to the next.

When you do `srand(<number>)` you select the book `rand()` will use from that point forward.

`time(NULL)` return the number (after conversion) of seconds since about midnight 1970-01-01. That number changes every second, so using that number to "select a book" pretty much guarantees a new sequence of "random" numbers every time your program runs.

If you don't select a book, the `rand()` function takes numbers from book #1 (same as `srand(1)`).

Having fixed random numbers may be useful in certain situations. For example, you want to test different functions with the same data.